# Java : Saving Date from JFormattedTextField MAsk to Access DB

Tags: java, ms-access, date, insert

I have a custom JFormattedTextfield for date that uses MaskFormatter `__/__/____` and patttern of "dd/MM/yyyy".
   To save to an object I use :

```
        try {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String dtStr = this.dateFormatTf.getValue().toString().trim();  // 01/01/2011
        java.util.Date dt =  df.parse(dtStr);  // dt = Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2011

        bk.setTransDate(dt);  // SAVes the date as util.Date in above way as dt
    } catch(java.text.ParseException e) { 
        Utility.logs.log(Level.WARNING, "Parse Date Exception = " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

After saving to an object, I try to generate sql insert command. Here, if I pass util.Date object, it gives exception as it can't store "Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2011" in DATE/TIME field of MS Access. Hence I tried the below to get sql.Date object :

```
     long tm = bk.getTransDate().getTime();
    java.sql.Date dt = new java.sql.Date(tm);
```

and pass dt to insert sql command. This saves the date in MS Access but the value stored is "01-07-1905".

What changes are required and where to make the date store in proper format from textfield to MS Access DB. 
In Access DB, the DATE field's format is set to SHORT.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what the case is with Java, but for the most part, you need to use US date format, or better, a yyyy/mm/dd format with MS Access and SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all,

I have seen Date issue in MS Access many times. Mostly I convert it to String/Text data type to help me store properly & cast as Date object properly in Application.

Well, this time also I ended using the same solution.